# Add new payment method in magento admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

How to add new payment method like bank transfer in magento admin panel?

I want fields like:

1. Enabled
2. Title
3. Instructions.

under payment method settings.

[image: Bank transfer Payment]

Answer (score 1):

**Create a module for this!**

You can take a look on [this](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-magento-payment-module/) link to see how they make a new custom module!

Hope this link will help you!

Comment: that should be in `etc` folder